# How do you bookmark, keep an eye on a question on askubuntu

Tags: discussion

I want to follow this question which is hard to find and do not have an answer yet but will soon have one(hopefully). Any shortcuts, bookmark tool?

P.S: The question is by Diego, tags are: 16.04; updates; login; console. It would be awesome if you can help to answer it

Answer (score 2):

You can STAR the post (down from the voting tab) and that will mark your question as fav. Shame you can't get updates...

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1

See this star inside a circle ?

[image]

Click that. It will add a question to your favorites tab

[image]

---

#### Method 2

There's also RSS feed below each question:

[image]

---

#### Method 3

Highlight the address bar in your web browser . . .

[image]

. . . and drag it to your desktop. In a second , it will create link which upon double-clicking will open the question in your default browser

[image]

---

EOF